# cannot connect to neo4j local graph through mule 4

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, anypoint-studio, mule4

When I use the BOLT url and REST URL to connect to localgraph database I get the following error.Getting error that connection to database terminated due to network instabilities or restarts to the database.

```
<neo4j:config name="Neo4j_Desktop" doc:name="Neo4j Config" doc:id="d81dfd26-b2fa-4432-a593-e2f98c080e2e" >
        <neo4j:connection username="neo4j" password="${neo4j.pwd}" boltUrl="bolt://127.0.0.1:7687" restUrl="http://127.0.0.1:7474" />
    </neo4j:config>
```

[image: neo4j configuration in mule 4]

Comment: What is the configuration in the Mule app? Please share as XML, not screenshots. Which exact versions of Mule and connectors are used? Also paste the complete error message shown in the screenshot as text.

Comment: I have edited my question .Any suggestions on this problem???

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean that you had to remove the screenshot of the error. In this particular error it was relevant. I just wanted that you added the XML configuration (partially added) and the complete stack trace of the error, from the bottom text box of the error. I see that you added the flow, however you should also add the neo4j connector configuration ("Neo4j_Config"). If it has any confidential data like passwords I recommend that you mask them.

Comment: I have updated my config details .Any advice from you??? Ran the mule application.Gives a connectivity error

Comment: From the screenshot It is not even clear what connector are you using. Please share the XML configuration, version of the connector, libraries and versions.

Comment: I am using Neo4jv.3.0 connector in Mule 4.Neo4j desktop 1.2.8.And Neo4j version 4.0.4.ABove is the XML config of my neo4j connector.

Comment: I want a solution to this as I want to  connect it with my Anypoint studio.Any insights would be appreciated